# How to catch inherited exceptions in Xunit.net

Tags: c#, xunit.net

So I have a custom Exception called `FoobarException`, and from that I created a new exception `FooException : FoobarException`  The following throws a FooException

```
Assert.Throws<FoobarException>(() => a.DoFoo(123));
```

Yet the assertion is failing because it is expecting `FooException` to be thrown.  Isn't a "FooException" also a FoobarException?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not in the way that XUnit examines it. To see for yourself, look at the code:

[XUnit Assert Exceptions](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.assert/Asserts/ExceptionAsserts.cs)

If you want to catch any exception or derived type, then you need to use the `ThrowsAny` overload.

```
Assert.ThrowsAny<Foobar>(() => a.DoFoo(123));
```

And just for a matter of "best practices", when creating exceptions, always end the name of the exception with the word "exception". Your exception above then becomes `FoobarException`, this makes it clear what the class is for. This is in the C# coding best practices and is very sound advice.

Comment: Thanks for the exception naming tip.  I was running into a meeting and got lazy typing it up here.  I'll correct it for historical purposes in case someone comes across this again.

Comment: BTW, where is the documentation for Xunit?  I see a simple FAQ, but I can barely find anything about catching exceptions.

Comment: link is broken, maybe [this one is relevant](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/test/test.xunit.assert/Asserts/ExceptionAssertsTests.cs#L156)?

Comment: @yair [This link would be the new one](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/efbe6a91019b32d8f2426db6da746f073fac01af/ExceptionAsserts.cs), but I don't think I want to update the original question because it'll bump a 3 year old answered question back to the homepage.

Comment: @RonBeyer I have no idea what's wrong with buming the question however old, but thanks for the new link! :)